# What does 'security: IsTrusted" in java console mean?

Tags: java, security, certificate, jnlp

When I try to load my jnlp, I see in the java console these logs

```
security: Istrusted: {myJNLP} false
security: Trusted libraries list file not found
```

All the jar files in the resources of JNLP are signed with proper certificates (that means they are not self-signed)

What would be the factor that cause the JNLP is not trusted ? Does it have any bad impact on my application if it is always trusted false ?

Thanks if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

What Java version are you using? I guess it is 1.7.0_XX.

The first warning could be that you didn't [sign](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/signedJNLP.html) your jnlp file.

The 2nd warning(s) are about the trusted-library tag which is missing in your 3rd party jar files manifest. For more information read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html).